# Stage3D: is it still required to clear a target buffer before drawing to it

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, stage3d

I read at several places (for example in the starling source code https://github.com/PrimaryFeather/Starling-Framework/blob/master/starling/src/starling/textures/RenderTexture.as) that it is required in stage3D to clear a Texture (or backbuffer) each time after it has been bound as render target and before rendering triangles into it (therefore making it impossible to create accumulation effects without buffer swapping).

I wonder, does this still hold true and is there any piece of official documentation on this behaviour or explanation on why this is required? I'm asking because I'm currently not clearing my renderTexture and am not receiving any error messages, but currently see some unexpected behaviour of which I don't know if it may be connected to me not clearing the texture (I'm using AIR 3.8).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been clearing textures after drawing. I HAVE had to clear textures that have been set by another object but aren't used in the drawing process for the current object. Does that make sense?